# Access a global object by its name than module

Tags: python-3.x, singleton, config

I have a module where I read a config file and store it into a variable.

Eg: `myconfig.py` looks like:

```
cfg = {}

def load(file_path):
    global cfg
    cfg = cfg_file_todict(file_path)
```

This `load()` function is called in a `main()` function (i.e. at beginning of the process).

I observe that the `cfg` variable cannot be imported directly, but it has to accessed via the module name.

I.e., say I have a file `a.py` where:

```
import myconfig

print(myconfig.cfg) # This prints the config properly across modules
```

But if I have:

```
from myconfig import cfg
print(cfg) # This prints None
```

Is there some way where even the second type of import can still retain the original variable? Or is there some other alternative to this?

Comment: Why use a "global" keyword outside a function? Isn't it stopping import process?

Answer (score 0):

#You can use a global variable within other functions by declaring it as global within each function that assigns a value to it:

globvar = 0

def set_globvar_to_one():
global globvar    # Needed to modify global copy of globvar
globvar = 1

def print_globvar():
print(globvar)     # No need for global declaration to read value of globvar

set_globvar_to_one()
print_globvar()       # Prints 1

Comment: For future reference, putting three backticks on the lines above and below a block of code is an easy way to make it format as a block of code, with multiple lines and indentation: like `\`\`\`[enter] this [enter] \`\`\``. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks is a more complete overview, if you'd like

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I guess you didn't get my question's meaning